# Ingresar datos mediante prompt y almacenarlos en un array

Tags: array, while, push, prompt

Estoy intentando resolver un problema que implica ingresar números a través de prompt y luego almacenarlos en un array. Cuando el usuario ingrese "stop" debe salir y mostrar el array. Les paso el código que estoy haciendo ya que no logro ver dónde está el error de mi lógica. Lo que he encontrado en la web tampoco he podido hacerlo funcionar. Este código que les muestro, me genera el prompt para ingresar los datos, pero nunca para, aún cuando se cumple la condición de parada; y es lo más cerca de hacerlo funcionar que estuve.
Desde ya, les agradezco cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme.
Saludos.

var input;
var cont = [];

while (input !== "stop") {

```
input = prompt ("ingrese dato:");

cont.push(input);
input++;
```

}

console.log (cont);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se presenta al hacer el `input++`, cuando se ingresa el string **"stop"** funciona la lógica del `while` pero cuando intenta hacer el **++** a "stop", esto retorna **NaN** como resultado de `input`, entonces `input` realmente no es el string "stop" por lo cual el `while` nunca termina.

Para resolverlo sencillamente debes borrar el `input++`, quedando algo así:

```
var input;
var cont = [];

while (input !== "stop") {
  input = prompt("ingrese dato:");
  cont.push(input);
}

console.log(cont);
```

Otra cosa que podrías tener presente es que el string **"stop"** también lo agrega al array en la última vuelta del `while`, por lo que podrías quizás agregar un `if` para que solo se haga el `push` si el `input` es diferente a **"stop"**. Quedando así:

```
var input;
var cont = [];

while (input !== "stop") {
  input = prompt("ingrese dato:");
  if (input !== "stop") {
    cont.push(input);
  }
}

console.log(cont);
```

Espero sirva para evacuar tu duda, quedo a las órdenes.

Comment: Me alegro mucho, favor marcar la pregunta como resuelta dando click sobre el visto al costado de la respuesta, así no queda pendiente para siempre, ayuda a mejorar la reputación y sirve a otros usuarios para saber que es una solución aceptada que pueden aprovechar. Gracias, buena jornada!

Comment: Estimado Luis @Luis S. Romero, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Anduvo perfecto el código sin el input++. Un abrazo. Saludos.